# Deploying iOS app that supports watchOS2

Tags: app-store, ios9, apple-watch, watchos-2

My iOS app supports from iOS 8.0+ and watchOS2 that works only in iOS 9+. For app store submission, is only iOS target archive enough?

Answer (score 1):

iOS8+ involves iOS9+. In that case your app supports watchOS2.